# How to track screen time in Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, browser-action

I'm building a browser extension as part of my website for self-discipline and anti-procrastination, one of the core features is to track users' **active usage** of each website. Just like how Apple tracks our screen time, I wish to have an extension to record the users' interactions with the browser to be later analyzed by users themselves.

Is there any way I can do that with the chrome extension APIs or any other APIs? Please help, thanks!

Comment: There's no such API. You can use a content script to add standard listeners for mousemove, keydown, visibilitychange and so on.